# What's an example of an NSString for which -UTF8String returns NULL?

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsstring

I see crash reports from which I can infer that -UTF8String returns NULL, but I haven't found any string which does so. Can anyone provide an example of a string that, at least for some OS version greater than or equal to 9.0, returns NULL for -UTF8String? It would be nice for unit tests, etc.

Comment: Are you perhaps referencing the `UTF8String` after the parent `NSString` has been deallocated? The pointer to the C string returned by `UTF8String` will not live longer than the `NSString` that it came from, so you may be inadvertently referencing garbage data

Comment: No, that's not what's happening here. In that case, the pointer would at least be non-null. -UTFString is documented as being nullable, so it's not a totally unexpected case. It's just hard to make it happen.

Comment: If `myString` is `nil`, `[myString UTF8String]` will be null.

Comment: Yes, this is not that case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of a high surrogate without a low surrogate that does it.

```
unichar c = 0xd800;
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&c length:1];
assert(s.UTF8String == NULL);
```

Comment: would this be considered a valid string?

Comment: RFC 2781, which defines UTF-16, calls this an illegal sequence, but cautions you to handle them.